# Filling picxturebox with byte array causes strange effect

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm writing in c# and using this to fill my `PictureBox` with a byte array

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(48, 32, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                           ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

Marshal.Copy(fileArray, 0, bmpData.Scan0, fileArray.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

return bmp;
```

The result is very strange.

It only fills up to the 125th byte. So I tried playing with the data and the 0-125 bytes show as they should but anything after byte 125 is not shown and it overwrites byte 125.

So if I do 0-125 all `0xff` I get as solid bar up top. but adding 126 as `0x00` it replaces 125 with `0x00`.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. I filled the bitmap with all the 256 possible values (random generated). I also changed the palette to Yellow/Red to identify eventual artifacts, but no problems arised. The resulting bitmap can be assigned to a PictureBox Image property or drawn on it.

Comment: not sure what I have wrong then I was able to look at it in closer detail. The first 6 bytes draw right but the 7th seems to have 11 bits inserted in front of it on that row. (6 bytes per row). That for testing though. Still struggling.

Comment: 8 bytes per row. If with "row" you mean the Bitmap Stride. The size of the array is `[BitmapData.Stride * Bitmap.Height]`.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the res here? MY res is 48 x 32, I have 6 bytes per row (6*8=48) (6 bytes 48 bits). If I draw only 6 bytes they are correct. if I draw 7 bytes the 7th is draw off screen (I dont see it).

Comment: You are filling the Bitmap data (`Marshal.Copy(...)`) with a byte array, starting at the address pointed by `BitmapData.Scan0`. The size of the array is `[BitmapData.Stride * Bitmap.Height]`. If you look at the `Stride`, it will say that it's size is `8`. In total, (8 * 32) 256 bytes.

Comment: Ok that helps, I didn't know about stride but it does make sense. Though setting the stride to 6 seems to not help.  bmpData.Stride = 6;

Comment: You can't set the Stride, you just need to use it to size your array. I don't understand why you keep referring to a value of `6`. You don't have to determine the Bitmap scan line size. You need to use that information for your calculations.

Comment: I'm confused because my image has a width of 6 bytes not 8. So if the stride is set to 8, I'm assuming it will take my byte 7 and byte 8 and write it on the first row of pixels. This  is exactly. what I'm seeing.  I guess I could insert padding (2 extra bytes after every 6 bytes of my data) but that seems rather silly?

Comment: Possibly I'm misunderstand something about images. The data I'm using comes from an LCD screen. Again 48x32 6 bytes per line not 8. So to redraw it on an image I'd have to some how tell the image my stride is 6. Sorry if I'm sounding redundant but I'm just not used to working with image data. Thank you for the help, hope you can tolerate a but more ?

Comment: The Stride is the number of bytes that the bitmap takes to represent one row of pixels. Not the raw `[Bitmap.Width / 8]`. You don't have to care about it. Just use this measure to size your array. (It's just 8 bytes because your `PixelFormat` is `Format1bppIndexed`, indexed palette of 2 colors). BTW, what's the content of your array? Just indexed colors, right?

Comment: but then the app blows up request range extends past array. Marshal.Copy(blob, 0, bmpData.Scan0, 256);

Comment: Post the code that shows what's inside the array and how the array is sized. You are still supposing that the Bitmap row is made of 6 bytes, so you size your array [6 * 32], right?.

Comment: that's what I was saying. My array is only 192 (6 bytes * 32 ). Here is the image (inverted but you will get the idea).https://pastebin.com/mVJYYDjf  I'm sure if I append two bytes for each row it would work.  Just seems odd to have to do that.

Comment: Those values in the array are not colors, at least not colors suited to represent colors in a Bitmap with `PixelFormat = Format1bppIndexed`. Using `BitmapData`, you fill the Bitmap bytes with colors, depending on the `PixelFormat`. When `PixelFomat` is `Format1bppIndexed`, each bit represents one of the two possible colors of the indexed palette. You're using the wrong method to recreate the data source. Where does the content of that array come from?

Comment: Ok that does help, I was getting advice on this as well. I was told Format1bppIndexed would work for monochrome. Bit 1 = white bit = black. This is the data format for writing to a monochrome LCD.

Comment: `Format1bppIndexed` can represent any color, but with a palette of just 2 colors. Black and White are two of the possible values. Rebuilding the source depends on what that data in the array come from. Btw, the BitmapData Stride (number of bytes required to represent a scan line), is always a multiple of 4, because it's aligned to 4 bytes for hardware compatibility.

Comment: So I added code above (ugly yes) but it does work to a degree. I tried to add 2 bytes at the end of every stride. half the the image loads then it repeats itself backwards. (mirror image). I hate to do it this way but I just can not find support for a byte array that holds b/w data with 1 bit depth. (1=white: 2= black) each bit is 1 pixel.

Comment: You can add row by row as well instead of just one block. But if you want just one move you need to have the padding in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting the padding into your data you can move the data row by row:

```
int w = 48;
int h = 32;
int unpadded = w / 8;   // unpadded byte length of one line in your data

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h,  PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

int stride = 8 // padded length of scanline

for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    Marshal.Copy(blob, i * unpadded , bmpData.Scan0 + i * stride, unpadded );  
}
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
return bmp;
```

Note that to make bitmap operations faster all physical rows must have a length that's a multiple of 4 bytes. The resulting, padded length is called [stride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line),
>   rounded up to a four-byte boundary. If the stride is positive, the
>   bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is
>   bottom-up.

With a logical length of 48 pixels and 1bpp your logical length is 6 bytes, so it must be padded to 8 bytes internally.

Best not to move your data in managed code to prepare this but to move only the right portions to the right slots..

Here are more [examples of calculating stride for other formats](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+stride)

Comment: Taw, love it. Very education!

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. Its by far not the best and shows a lack of understanding or simply bitmaps can not support monochrome 1 bit per pixel images. Never the less it works. All this does is adds 2 bytes on each row of 6 bytes. So that the stride can deal with it.

```
int j = 1;
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 192; i++)
{
    fixArray[k] = blob[i];
    j++;
    if (j == 7)
    {
        j = 1;
        fixArray[++k] = 0;
        fixArray[++k] = 0;
    }
    k++;
}
```